Need help in tikzpicture
I'm trying to draw this plot
,
I've done the triangle, but I'm not able to draw the curves between $A_1$ to $A_2$, between $A_3$ to $B_3$ etc.
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \path[draw, line width=1.5pt](7,7)--(7,0)--(3,3.5)--cycle;
       \draw[blue, thick] (7, 5) .. controls (5.5,5.8) .. (6, 6.1);
   \end{tikzpicture}

Can anyone give some suggestions, on how to do it?

What are the characteristics of these curves? Are they part of circles or something else?

Show us how you have “done the triangle”. And answer @Stephen's question. What defines the points A and B? What specifies the curves?

@Qrrbrbirlbel, I've written the code for the triangle, and in answering Stephen's question, I've noted that these are not part of circles; they are random curves.

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (7,7) coordinate (A)
    (7,0) coordinate (B)
    (3,3.5) coordinate (C)
    ($(A)!0.25!(B)$) coordinate (A1) node[right] {$A_1$}
    ($(A)!0.3!(C)$) coordinate (A2) node[above left] {$A_2$}
    ($(A)!0.6!(C)$) coordinate (A3) node[above left] {$A_3$}
    ($(B)!0.25!(A)$) coordinate (B1) node[right] {$B_1$}
    ($(B)!0.3!(C)$) coordinate (B2)  node[below left] {$B_2$}
    ($(B)!0.6!(C)$) coordinate (B3)  node[below left] {$B_3$};
\draw[blue,thick] (A1) to[bend left=20] (A2)
    (A1) to[bend left=20] (A3)
    (B1) to[bend right=20] (B2)
    (B1) to[bend right=20] (B3);
\draw[red,thick] (A2) to[bend right=30] (B2)
    (A3) to[bend left=10] (B3);
\draw[line width=1.5pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Instead of controls, I use in/out angles specifications.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw, line width=1.5pt](7,7)--(7,0) node [pos=.3,label={0:$A_1$}] (A1) {} node [pos=.6,label={0:$B_1$}] (B1) {} -- (3,3.5) node [pos=.4,label={[anchor=north east]0:$B_2$}] (B2) {} node [pos=.7,label={[anchor=north east]0:$B_3$}] (B3) {}--cycle node [pos=.3,label={[anchor=south east]0:$A_3$}] (A3) {} node [pos=.6,label={[anchor=south east]0:$A_2$}] (A2) {};
    \draw [blue, thick] (A1.center) to [out=170, in=-30] (A2.center);
    \draw [blue, thick] (A1.center) to [out=190, in=-20] (A3.center);
    \draw [red, thick] (A2.center) to [out=-100, in=100] (B2.center);
    \draw [red, thick] (A3.center) to [out=-80, in=80] (B3.center);
    \draw [blue, thick] (B1.center) to [out=170, in=30] (B2.center);
    \draw [blue, thick] (B1.center) to [out=170, in=20] (B3.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Purely for comparison, here is a Metapost version.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  path triangle;
  triangle = origin -- 100 up -- 100 left -- 100 down -- cycle;

  pair A[], B[];

  A1 = point 0.42 of triangle;
  A2 = point 1.4 of triangle;
  A3 = point 1.6 of triangle;
  B1 = point -0.42 of triangle;
  B2 = point -1.4 of triangle;
  B3 = point -1.6 of triangle;

  def connector(expr a, b, r) = 
    a {(b-a) rotated r} .. b
  enddef;

  draw connector(A1, A2, +14) withcolor 2/3 blue;
  draw connector(A1, A3, +16) withcolor 2/3 blue;
  draw connector(B1, B2, -14) withcolor 2/3 blue;
  draw connector(B1, B3, -16) withcolor 2/3 blue;
  draw connector(A2, B2, -12) withcolor 3/4 red;
  draw connector(A3, B3, +12) withcolor 3/4 red;

  draw triangle withpen pencircle scaled 3/4;

  forsuffixes @ = A, B:
    label.rt("$" & str @ & "_1$", @1);
  endfor

  for i=2, 3:
    label.ulft("$A_" & decimal i & "$", A[i]);
    label.llft("$B_" & decimal i & "$", B[i]);
  endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:


\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        my angle1/.style = {draw,thick,red, %,fill=teal!30,
            angle radius=24mm, 
            angle eccentricity=1.1, 
            right, inner sep=1pt,
            font=\small}
        ]
\draw[thick] (6,0) coordinate[%label=below:$A$
](a) 
    --(0,5) coordinate[%label=below:$C$
    ](c) 
    --(6,10) coordinate[%label=above:$B$
    ](b) 
    -- cycle;
\path (6,10) coordinate (A)
    (6,0) coordinate (B)
    (0,5) coordinate (C)
    ($(A)!0.25!(B)$) coordinate (A1) node[right] {$A_1$}
    ($(A)!0.3!(C)$) coordinate (A2) node[above left] {$A_2$}
    ($(A)!0.6!(C)$) coordinate (A3) node[above left] {$A_3$}
    ($(B)!0.25!(A)$) coordinate (B1) node[right] {$B_1$}
    ($(B)!0.3!(C)$) coordinate (B2)  node[below left] {$B_2$}
    ($(B)!0.6!(C)$) coordinate (B3)  node[below left] {$B_3$};
\draw[thick,red] (2.325,6.9) arc (235:327:2.6);
\draw[thick,red] (6.0,2.4) arc (30:127:2.6);
\draw[thick,blue] (2.15,3.2) arc (330:385:4);
\draw[thick,blue] (4.2,8.5) arc (150:210:7);
\pic[my angle1] {angle = c--b--a};
\pic[my angle1] {angle = b--a--c};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


